# how to get high-dpi activity-icons from another app for my launcher-app?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, icons

i want to get from another app on device an activity icon with the highest possible resolution, but cant figure out how to do it......

In my app i can select one activity from a list of all activities available on the device and the correspondig intent will return to onActivityResult. There i can get the activities icon like this:

```
    Drawable icon = null;
    ComponentName componentName = intent.getComponent();
    String packageName = componentName.getPackageName();        
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    icon = pm.getActivityIcon(intent);
```

i can then get the app-icon with the highest resolution like this:

```
PackageInfo pi = pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
Context otherAppCtx = this.createPackageContext(packageName, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);

int displayMetrics[] = { DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH, DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXXHIGH };

for (int displayMetric : displayMetrics)
{
    try
    {
           Drawable d = otherAppCtx.getResources().getDrawableForDensity(pi.applicationInfo.icon, displayMetric); 


            if (d != null)
            {
                icon = d;
            }
    }
    catch (Resources.NotFoundException e)
    {

            continue;
    }
}
```

Thats nice but i want to get the activity icon and not the app icon with the highest resolution. Does anyone know how to do this?

thx in advance!

Comment: by activity icon you mean app icon?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about violating copyrights.

Comment: @tyczj  no activity-icon, for example: the contacs-app on android has several activities. One of them is phone-activity, which has a phone-symbol (which i get in the first part of the posted code). But the app-icon is the "people"-icon (which i get  in the second part of my code).

Comment: @Dan S: i dont think so. There are many apps out there which launch other activities on the phone and use for that their icons. cant imagine they are all illegal! and i dont want to steal these icons or something.

Comment: @maltonic42 True but focusing on getting a specific type didn't make me think you were making a launcher or utility.

Comment: @Dan S: Yes i do make a launcher and want to have the best quality so that it looks as good as possible. I also do scaling to bigger sizes.....hope that makes it clear enough ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track with it, you just need to use `ActivityInfo` instead of `PackageInfo`. e.g. where you have:

```
Drawable icon = null;
ComponentName componentName = intent.getComponent();
String packageName = componentName.getPackageName();        
PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
icon = pm.getActivityIcon(intent);
```

Instead of getting the drawable, get the icon resource (if one is set):

```
ComponentName componentName = intent.getComponent();
ActivityInfo ai = this.getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(componentName, 0);
int iconResId = ai.icon;
```

Then you should be able to use your second method to resolve it by density.

Comment: i felt that i was close, but.....gosh that was easy ;) thank you so much for this and also for the clear and precise explanation! cheers! ;)

Comment: @ kcoppock: no problems, only situations ;)